# Int Variable in C Changing When Not Called

Tags: c, cs50

Apologies in advance, I'm very new to this.

I am attempting to score "scrabble words" according to a `POINTS` array with associated score values.

1. I first get the length of the string of `word1`.
2. I then create a `for` loop that takes the value of the lower case letter minus 97 (to get to the 0 index) and adds it to the array.

You can ignore the rest of the code, as this is where the issue lies.  While the `stringlength` variable is only defined once, I've found that it somehow changes during the second cycle of the `for` loop.  A four letter word will originally have a `stringlength` of `4`, however the `for` loop changes it to `1` on the second run.

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };

int main(void) {
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    int stringlength = strlen(word1);

    int array[] = {};
    int array2[] = {};

    //Create an array with each letter
    for (int index = 0; index < stringlength; index++) {
        //THE BELOW LINE IS WHERE "STRINGLENGTH" CHANGES TO "1" ON THE SECOND LOOP
        array[index] = word1[index] - 97;
        array2[index] = POINTS[array[index]];
    }

    int score = 0;

    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < stringlength; index2++)
        score += array2[index2];

    printf("%i", stringlength);

    printf("\n");
}
```

I know I could just create a secondary `stringlength` variable but I know that's bad programming and I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Both `array` and `array2` have size 0. You can't just add things to it.

Comment: @tkausl Please create an answer.

Comment: *lower case letter minus 97* Don't do this. Never use magic numbers if you can use the real thing. Use `-'a'` instead of `-97`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `int array[] = {};` is a syntax error. There must be at least one initializer for an array definition. In your case, you must define `array` with a length of `stringlength` with:

  ```
  int array[stringlength];
  ```

  your compiler seems to accept the definition and create an empty array, which is not long enough to store the letter scores: you have undefined behavior in both `for` loops, accessing array elements beyond their boundaries. Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including what you observe.
- in `word1[index] - 97`, you hard code the ASCII value of `'a'`. This is bad practice, you should write this instead:

  ```
  word1[index] - 'a'
  ```

  note however that you also make 2 more silent assumptions in this expression:

  - you assume that `word1` only contains lowercase letters, which should be tested as the user can type any string.
  - you assume that the lowercase letters form are contiguous in the execution character set, which is correct for ASCII but not guaranteed by the C Standard. Since all modern systems use ASCII for the standard characters, this assumption is OK.
- `printf("%i", stringlength);` outputs the string length, not the score.

Here is a modified version without additional arrays:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };

int main(void) {
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    //Compute the score for player 1
    int score1 = 0;
    for (int index = 0; word1[index] != '\0'; index++) {
        unsigned char c = word1[index];
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            // assuming ASCII character set
            score1 += POINTS[c - 'a'];
        }
    }

    //Compute the score for player 2
    int score2 = 0;
    for (int index = 0; word2[index] != '\0'; index++) {
        unsigned char c = word2[index];
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            // assuming ASCII character set
            score2 += POINTS[c - 'a'];
        }
    }
    printf("Player 1: %d\n", score1);
    printf("Player 2: %d\n", score2);
    return 0;
}
```

If you know about functions, you could write a function `int compute_score(const char *word)` to avoid duplicating the code and improve readability.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response.  

I was unaware that I couldn't initialize an empty array.  As for the hardcoded 97/'a', I also wasn't aware I could use a character in place of the ASCII numeral.  Very good to know.  I was definitely going to build in additional compatibility for capital letters but wanted to build it out simply initially.

Also, I'm aware that the print statement provides the length.  Before running debug50, I was using this to debug to determine what was wrong.

I will run through your code example now and begin to make sense of it.

Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I attempted to mark his answer as accepted but it said I didn't have a high enough "reputation" since I was a brand new user.  I now do and have gone ahead and marked it.
Edit - scratch that, I'm mistaken.  It wouldn't allow me to "vote".  I now see there's an "accept this answer" button.

Comment: @Quinn Yep. There are a number of little widgets crammed around the answer and it just takes a bit to become familiar with all of them. Thanks for following through.